# Basic assembly addition (tasm)

Tags: assembly, tasm

I'm new in assembly and i just want to put the "+" and "=" between the inputs. Sorry for the english.

```
.model small
.stack 100h
.data
  symbol1 db 13,10,"+: $"
  symbol2 db 13,10,"=: $"
.code
start:
  mov ah,1
  int 21h

  mov bl,al
  int 21h
  add bl,al
  sub bl,30h
  mov ah,2
  mov dl,bl
  int 21h
  int 20h
end start
```

Comment: MS-DOS real mode, eh? What's the actual question? Are you unsure what interrupt to use? Then Ralf Brown's Interrupt list is a handy reference, e.g., http://www.ctyme.com/intr/int-21.htm

Comment: i just want to show the + and = sign on the output of the code.

Comment: So just show them? In your code I see `mov ah,2` `mov dl,bl` `int 21h` to display "result" of addition, so in the same way you can output any character loaded into DL, also `mov dl,'+'`. Or you can use `ah,9` "print string" service, check the [`int 21h` docs](http://stanislavs.org/helppc/int_21.html) (another link, if you don't like the one from Ove ... rather keep both), what services are available, and how to set up arguments for them.

Comment: On the `int 21h` doc, you can find the `AH = 09h` - write string to standard output

Answer (score -1):

Your idea is not completely wrong, so let's just give it a few tweaks.

```
    mov     ah, 1
    int     21H
    and     al, 15                 ; Mask out high nibble
    mov     bl, al
    ........                       ; Display plus sign
    int     21H
    and     al, 15
    add     bl, ah
    add     bl, 30H
    ..........                     ; Display equal sign
    mov     dl, bl
    mov     ah, 2
    int     21H
    ret
```

So if you press 5 and then 2 your screen could look like this, providing you insert appropriate code where necessary.

> 5+2=7

Your example judging by the prompting strings, you want something like this;

> 5
> +: 2
> =: 7

Either way, whatever you want to have happen with it either using function 2 or 9, you'd have to insert that code at the ellipses. There are a few problems though.

1. What if you don't enter a digit between 0 - 9
2. What if the result is greater than 10.
3. What if the range of values is greater than a single digit, like 0 - 99